# Add Brightness and Contrast to Cropper JS without Caman JS?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, cropperjs, camanjs

Because [CamanJS is no longer maintained](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS), does anyone know of a newer lightweight solution to add brightness and contrast adjustment to [Cropper JS](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) like this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/goneale/pen/QyqXGv?editors=101)?

HTML:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Cropper</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.2.4/cropper.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="page-header">Use Cropper with CamanJS</h1>
      <p id="upload">
        <input id="file" type="file" />
      </p>
      <p id="handle" style="display: none;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="brightness">Brightness</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="contrast">Contrast</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.1.2/caman.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.2.4/cropper.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
$(function () {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var $upload = $("#upload");
  var $handle = $("#handle");
  var $file = $("#file");
  var $canvas = $("#canvas");
  var caman;

  function startCropper() {
    // Destroy if already initialized
    if ($canvas.data("cropper")) {
      $canvas.cropper("destroy");
    }

    // Initialize a new cropper
    $canvas.cropper({
      crop: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      },
    });
  }

  function startCaman(url) {
    caman = Caman("#canvas", url, function () {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      //$upload.hide();
      $handle.show();

      startCropper();
    });
  }

  $handle.hide();

  if (URL) {
    $file.change(function () {
      var files = this.files;
      var file;

      if (files && files.length) {
        file = files[0];

        if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
          startCaman(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        } else {
          window.alert("Please choose an image file.");
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    $file.prop("disabled", true);
  }

  $("#brightness").on("click", function () {
    if (caman) {
      caman.brightness(20).render(startCropper);
    }
  });

  $("#contrast").on("click", function () {
    if (caman) {
      caman.contrast(10).render(startCropper);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not just download it, and put it on your server if you wish to keep using it?

Comment: I don't feel like using something that isn't going to be maintained...I am currently using it, but looking for other options

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 `filter:` rule can do these tasks naively in the browser. It supports
numerous operations:

```
filter: none | blur() | brightness() | contrast() | drop-shadow() | grayscale() | 
    hue-rotate() | invert() | opacity() | saturate() | sepia() | url();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp